# MYSQL equal one id with two different ids

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:
professor

> ```
>      id_prof   numep       prenumep   
>        1        bla         bla  
>        2        bla         bla  
>        3        bla         bla
> ```

exam

> ```
>      id_ex  id_prof1     id_prof2   
>        1        1             3  
>        2        2             1  
>        3        3             2
> ```

I want to show all exams with:

```
 $sqll = "SELECT * FROM exam, professor WHERE id_prof=id_prof1 AND id_prof = id_prof2 " ;
                $result = mysqli_query($link,$sqll);

            while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['numep']." ".$rows['prenumep']; ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $rows['numep']." ".$rows['prenumep']; ?></td> 

                </tr> 

            }
```

It doesn't show anything. But if I delete one of the `id_prof=id_prof1` or the other it shows only one professor. What should I do to show both of them? I want to have at the end Date Exam Professor Assistent etc to show. and prof1 and prof2 si for professor and assistent. here i said only a part of it because only this didn't work

Comment: you're using `AND`, therefore you want only records where the id_prof1 and id_prof2 fields have the SAME value. try `OR` instead.

Comment: pleas add to your question that what output you want ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should be doing `left join` to `professor` table 2 times to get the data and if some professor data is deleted it will be shown as null in the result, something as

```
select 
e.id_ex,
p1.numep as numep1,
p1.prenumep as prenumep1,
p2.numep as numep2,
p2.prenumep as prenumep2
from exam e
left join professor p1 on p1.id_prof = e.id_prof1
left join professor p2 on p2.id_prof = e.id_prof2
```

Comment: why you used `join` ? I think `union` is more better.

Comment: No without join how will you know the `numep` and `prenumep` from `prefessor` table when you have ids in `exam` table ?

Comment: you right ..! one other question: why you used `join` ?, you could use it: `SELECT * FROM exam, professor`

Comment: Well `SELECT * FROM exam, professor` is called implicit join and its no longer being used by programmer. Now its nothing but inner join and this mean there has to be matching record in both tables. Think one professor is deleted from professor table and doing inner join will not display that row having that professor id, hence left join so that even if the professor is deleted we get data from exam table and with null values if professor data is not available in the professor table.

Comment: WOW, got it ...! In fact i have tow dictionary table and want to search in them, Now what do you suggest?? In oder word i want search in `table1` for a word and then search in `table2` for the same word. `union all` or `join`?

Comment: Ok that entirely depends on the DB schema, create a question with the schema and some sample data with expected result.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm limited on stack :( !! I can't create a question !

Comment: Every one can create a question even with 1 reputation.

Comment: Your reputation is too much and you can't understand my problem :D !!!, I asked a question already and the question got negative score, then i can't create question any more!

Comment: table1[id,word,mean] - table2[id,word,mean] - (word is indexed). how search in both of word's column with i query ?

Comment: If you want that the word must be in both tables then use join else union should do the trick

Comment: I have changed one of my previous questions, may check and answer to me pal ? tnx alot (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746486/using-union-all-or-join-for-two-table)

Comment: And if i have another ids with other relations besides those , i will have to use left join for all ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM exam, professor WHERE id_prof=id_prof1 AND id_prof = id_prof2
```

You are looking for some id_prof witch, in tabla "exam" you had something like

```
id_ex  id_prof1     id_prof2   
   1        1             1
   2        3             3
```

etc...

change the query into:

```
SELECT * FROM exam, professor WHERE id_prof=id_prof1 OR id_prof = id_prof2
```